# Passing a boolvalue from a UITableViewCell to the parent UITableViewController then remove the cell based on the boolvalue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My TableView loads the tableView, it's DataSource is from a remote JSON that is serialized. The TableView creates the number of cells necessary from the count of the array. Then, the TableView loads the Cells...the Cell has it's own class subclassed as a UITableViewCell.

So, now to the question:

The cell sends an ICMP ping to a machine. If the ping is successful, I want the cell removed from the TableView with no user interaction.

How can this be done?

Comment: The cell actually sends an ICMP ping to a machine. If the ping is successful, I want the cell removed from the TableView with no user interaction.

Comment: You have to save all your cells in an array, so you can remove a specific position that ping successfuly and after you reload your TableView.

Comment: That's a great idea, however here's my question. The TableView is it's own class, and the cell's are their own class as well. So each cell pings it's own object...as per the indexPath. So how can I gather an array of boolvalues with multiple Cells?

Comment: You can use a tag. `cell.tag = 1 || 0` 1 for successful 0 for not. if  your cell has `cell.tag == 1` remove it.

Comment: Simplicity at it's best. Can't believe I didn't think about that. I thank you sir.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. Do you mind to select my answer as correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the tag of your cell.

```
cell.tag = 1; // cell.tag = 0;
```

You can use 1 for successful and 0 for not.

```
if(cell.tag == 1) {
    // Do something! Remove it.
}
```

I'm glad this helpd you.

Comment: Thank you! That helped immensely!